# How to get the name of the view of a Constraint when we have LayoutConstraints Error?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard

when we have some LayoutConstraint Error we can see an error like this in the console:

`[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.`

we can use this extention and set the identifier for finding that broken constraint:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    override open var description: String {
        let id = identifier ?? ""
        return "id: \(id), constant: \(constant)"
    }
}
```

but it is too hard to set the identifiers for all of the constraints especially when we are reusing a lot of views in one view.
in my case, I have more than 2500 constraints in the app.

so:

1. how to get the view of that constraint with that extension code?

OR

2. how to set the identifier for all of the constraints in the storyboard file easily?

thanks

Comment: A better approach would be to keep a reference of the constraints you want to enable and disable and manipulate the property `isActive` as required.

Comment: Not really able to help you with identifier, but when this happens, I would try to use view debugger, because it shows you conflicting constraints